# Laravel 5.5 jQuery 3.3.1 ajax is not a function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, twilio

I've been developing a callcenter app with twilio and laravel 5.5, I want to get webrtc capabilities in my app and for that i have to use ajax to make requests.

however i am getting the following warning:

> jQuery.Deferred exception: $.ajax is not a function
>   @http://localhost:8000/js/browser-calls.js:14:2
>   l@http://localhost:8000/js/jquery.js:2:29373
>   a/http://localhost:8000/js/jquery.js:2:2967

with the following error:

> TypeError: $.ajax is not a function

I've searched high and low for solutions and I've tried the folowing:

1. download jquery from the cdn to client and include it
2. try the latest CDN `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`
3. Tested in edge, chrome, firefox
4. check if I'm not accidentally using the slim build
5. place everything in my app.blade.php's header below jquery instead of right before the `</body>`

`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/client/v1.3/twilio.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/browser-calls.js') }}"></script>`

nothing has been able to resolve the issue, this is my ajax call

```
    /* get twilio token with AJAX request */
var clientName = $('#agent-name').data('name');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',  
        url: '/twilio/generate-token', 
        data: {
            clientName: clientName,
        },
        success: function(data) {
            Twilio.Device.setup(data.token);
        }
    });
```

i also tried the `$.post` instead of `$.ajax` but it resulted in the same error.

```
$.post('/twilio/generate-token', {
    clientName: clientName,
    clientToken: this.clientToken
    }, function(data) {
        Twilio.Device.setup(data.token);
});
```

What the hell is causing the `$.ajax` function to not be recognized..

Comment: The error implies that you're using the 'slim' branch of jquery, which does not have AJAX and several other features. You said you've tried to add a full version of jQuery, but ensure you *only* include that version, and have removed any previous ones.

Comment: And make sure include jQuery before you include your js-code, so jQuery is available when your code is executed.

Comment: it apparently was caused by the app.js from laravel, if i load my local jquery and all the other scripts after the app.js it seems to work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The jquery liberary was included before the `app.js` script from laravel itself, after i moved the jquery cdn below the defenition of `app.js` the problem was fixed

Comment: Consider setting this question as answered by your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, but fixed it by adding this line:

```
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue and got a better solution, than including a second jQuery.
As I found out the app.js requires bootstrap.js.

In bootstrap.js the "jquery/dist/jquery.slim.js" is loaded, just change this to:
"jquery/dist/jquery.min.js" and after recompiling and loading page a few times the issue is solved in a cleaner way.

So problem was that the slim version of jQuery was loaded, which indeed does not contain any ajax feature.